# My wifi connection is really slow using Atheros chipset

Tags: networking, wireless, lenovo

I recently dual booted Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10, and I'm new to Linux.  I have a lenovo Ideapad 500, 16 gb RAM, AMD FX 8800.
After I installed Ubuntu the wifi wasn't working and I found a solution where you had to install the driver in a new directory (I think it was [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773542/ath10k-driver-not-working-hence-wifi-adoptor-qca6164-not-recognised)).

So my wifi is working now, but the problem is that the connection is slower than it is in Windows 10, the download speeds are slower and I confirmed with speedtest.net (In windows I get4-7 Mbps and in Ubuntu I'm getting ~0.5 Mbps). I tried a solution where you had to add a nohwcrypt command to a driver file (I think), and [this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508279/slow-wifi-on-atheros-ar9271-aka-tl-wn722n). But it doesn't work, the internet is still slow. 
This is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: 15
   serial: 1c:39:47:39:23:cb
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:228 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f0404000-f0404fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff

*-network
   description: Wireless interface
   product: QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlp2s0
   version: 20
   serial: c8:ff:28:55:b3:0b
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.4.0-36-generic firmware=SW_RM.1.1.1-00157-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.1.70 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
   resources: irq:235 memory:f0000000-f01fffff
```

And this is the outpot of `iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"INFINITUMlrfv"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.417 GHz  Access Point: 0C:96:BF:A9:48:F4   
      Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:196  Invalid misc:8   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: Before any further troubleshooting make sure you have the correct wireless encryption settings: WPA2-AES only, not any WPA/WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP.

Comment: @CelticWarrior I'm connecting through the network manager and it has only 2 options: WPA&WPA2 Personal and WPA&WPA2 Enterprise. How do I set it to WPA2-AES?

Comment: The settings are at the router managing that wireless network.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Okay, I set it to "Authentication: WPA2-PSK" and "Encryption: AES", but the problem persists.

Comment: See if there is any change after `sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off`

Comment: @Jeremy31 No changes. Also I tested the wifi in my university network and it was fine. So I think it has something to do with my modem or modem configuration.